# Resizing NSImage keeping aspect ratio reducing the image size while trying to scale up

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I'm using the following code to resize an `NSImage` by preserving the aspect ratio. But
this extension method keeps reducing the image size when I try to increment the same

```
func resizeMaintainingAspectRatio(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> NSImage? {
        let ratioX = (width/(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!) / size.width
        let ratioY = (height/(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!) / size.height
        var ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
        let newHeight = size.height * ratio
        let newWidth = size.width * ratio
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        let img = NSImage(size: canvasSize)
        img.lockFocus()
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current
        context?.imageInterpolation = .high
        draw(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: NSSize(width: newWidth,height: newHeight)), from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size) , operation: .copy, fraction: 1)
        img.unlockFocus()
        return img
    }
```

Usage:

```
    let w = CGFloat(logoimage!.size.width) + 10
    let h=CGFloat(logoimage!.size.height) + 10
    logoimage=originallogoimage?.resizeMaintainingAspectRatio(width: w, height: h)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `NSImage`'s member `size` does not give you the actual physical dimension of the image, but rather its backing store resolution on the screen which is screen resolution dependent (downscaled by the `-backingScaleFactor`).

In your code, while your `logoimage`'s underlying image representation still holds the actual physical dimension, you downscaled its size by the `-backingScaleFactor` (which scales down the actual dimension of the image) to get the ratio, causing the resultant image being even smaller as the new image uses a downscaled size derived by an already-downscaled size. This is redundant, for the conversion between the image's physical pixel resolution and the backing store resolution happens automatically.

By simply removing `backingScaleFactor` from the code, here's the code for `resizedMaintainingAspectRatio(width:height:)`:

```swift
extension NSImage {
    func resizedMaintainingAspectRatio(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
        let ratioX = width / size.width
        let ratioY = height / size.height
        let ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
        let newHeight = size.height * ratio
        let newWidth = size.width * ratio
        let newSize = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        let image = NSImage(size: newSize)
        image.lockFocus()
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current
        context!.imageInterpolation = .high
        draw(in: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize), from: NSZeroRect, operation: .copy, fraction: 1)
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
}
```

Since `lockFocus()` is deprecated after macOS 13.0, you can use `init(size:flipped:drawingHandler:)` instead:

```swift
extension NSImage {
    func resizedMaintainingAspectRatio(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
        let ratioX = width / size.width
        let ratioY = height / size.height
        let ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
        let newHeight = size.height * ratio
        let newWidth = size.width * ratio
        let newSize = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        let image = NSImage(size: newSize, flipped: false) { destRect in
            NSGraphicsContext.current!.imageInterpolation = .high
            self.draw(in: destRect, from: NSZeroRect, operation: .copy, fraction: 1)
            return true
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

Now the image should be resized to the correct size by doing the following:

```swift
logoimage = logoimage!.resizedMaintainingAspectRatio(width: logoimage!.size.width + 10,
                                                     height: logoimage!.size.height + 10)
```